# Pass a value from a row to another form

Tags: php

I have two php files, Articles.php and Details.php. What I want is when I click on a row on Articles.php, the ID is passed to Details.php. With the ID I can easily fill Details.php.

Here is a sample from Articles.php :

```
<form action="Articles.php" methode="GET">
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($MyQuerry))
    {   
        echo "<tr onclick='location.href=\"Details.php\"'>";
        echo '<td align="center">'.$row["ID"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["Symptome"].'</td>';
        echo '<td align="center">'.$row["Name"].'</td>';

        // I get the ID value from the clicked row
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="valueID" value="'.$row["ID"].'" />';

        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

I can click on any row I want and Details.php appears. I tried to get the `valueID` and to print it but it says "*Undefined index : valueID*".

Here is Details.php:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['valueID'];
    $id;    
?>
```

I think the problem comes from my form. I have form action to Articles.php because I can search articles with a textbox and a listbox.

My Articles.php works, I can search articles by categories and symptom, but I need to get the ID from a row I click.

If I use `method = "POST"` my search doesn't work anymore this is why I use the `method = "GET"`.

I wondered if I can open a post form into the get form just to pass the `valueID`.

Please ask if more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Articles.php try just using a link & query string:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($MyQuerry))
    {   
        echo "<tr onclick='location.href=\"Details.php\"'>";
        echo '<td align="center">'.$row["ID"].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row["Symptome"].'</td>';
        echo '<td align="center">'.$row["Name"].'</td>';

        // I get the ID value from the clicked row
        echo '<a href="Details.php?valueID=' . $row['ID'] . '">Link to Details</a>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

And don't forget to print the $id by using `echo $id;` in Details.php:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['valueID'];
    echo $id;    
?>
```

Comment: The "Undefined index" appears to the $id = $_GET['valueID']; line

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> If you are trying to send id to next page then use
> ```

```
 echo "<a href='Details.php?valueID=".$row["ID"]."' >Link name</a>";
```

Comment: Yes it works. It's ugly but it works. I add : echo "<td><a href='DetailArticle.php?valeurID=".$ligne["ID"]."' >Link name</a></td>";  in my table. Now i have a link at the begining of each rows that pass the id value. Thank you :) Have a Nice day :)